# remote login pass command then wait and pass commands

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, expect

I am an average unix user but unable to find solution to the following problem.

Problem statement:

1. run this command from my terminal **(note i cannot change this command or alter)**

   ```
   ssh -N -f -L 50003:127.0.0.1:23 x.x.x.x; telnet 127.0.0.1 50003
   ```
2. This will login to x.x.x.x machine with some banner messages it will ask me to select from list of free ports e.g.,

   ```
   Select a terminal from the list below:
   (17,18,20,21,22,24)
   ```

   Now i need to pass any of these free port numbers i.e., 17 or 20 or 24
3. Once this number is provided it will display the following:

   ```
   Connection established as terminal 17.
   >
   ```
4. now i need to pass `login:uid=someusername` and press enter button
5. It will display the following

   ```
   Command entered at terminal #17.
   ;
   Enter Password :
   ```
6. Now i need to pass the password once provided i will login to another terminal which will display the following:

   ```
   ;
   Command Executed
   >
   ```
7. now i need to enter my command e.g., `runjob`

   Once the above command is provided it will run for some time lets say for 2 mins or 5 mins
8. once completed it will display

   ```
   Command Completed.
   ;
   ```

here i need to provide the command as `ctrlkey+]` (control key plus the closing square bracket)

then it will display following:

```
telnet>
```

again i need to pass `quit` and press Enter

once this is done i will exit, also all these interactions should be saved in a file for cross verification.

Currently i installed expect but unable to pass. please help

Comment: Do you have an expect script that you've tried for this? Does it work at all?

Comment: Try using `autoexpect` to record a session. Then we can help you trim out the unneeded stuff from the generated script.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. We don't provide whole scripts, we provide solutions for specific problems. Please show us the script that you have written, where it breaks (use a comment or explanation so we can find the line), how it breaks (error message), the input, the expected output, things like that.

Comment: Hi All, following is script

$ cat test1.sh
#!/bin/bash
ssh -N -f -L 50003:127.0.0.1:23 10.64.246.124; telnet 127.0.0.1 50003
$

$ cat script.sh
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn "./test1.sh"
expect "Select a terminal from the list below:" { send "18\r" }

expect "Connection established as terminal" { send "login:uid=inventory\r" }

expect "Enter Password" { send "flask1234!\r" }
expect "Command Executed" { send "rtrv-stp\r" }

sleep 50

expect "Command Executed" { send "" }
expect "telnet" {send "quit\r" }
interact
$

Answer (score 0):

Dear Stackoverflow forum,

After breaking my head for almost a week found the solution.

### ***Problem Statement

From S1 (Server1) i need to login to S2 (server2) provide interactive commands and get the output captured in my S1.***

### Solution

```
[weblogic@ tmp]$ cat test1.sh
#!/bin/bash

ssh -N -f -L 50002:127.0.0.1:23 10.64.246.124; telnet 127.0.0.1 50002
[weblogic@ tmp]$



[weblogic@ tmp]$ cat check.sh
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn "./test1.sh"

expect "Select*" { send "24\r" }
sleep 1
expect "Connection*" { send "login:uid=inventory\r" }
expect "Enter*" { send "flask1234!\r" }
sleep 1
expect "Command*" { send "rtrv-stp\r" }
sleep 90
expect "Command*" { send "" }
expect "telnet" {send "q\r" }
interact
[weblogic@ tmp]$
```

Following command will capture all my logs to check for success/failure

```
[weblogic@ tmp]$ ./check.sh >>out.log
```

**I am sure this script will guide other people who might come across with similar problem.**

Dear forum though i get almost all my queries from you but in this case i was on my own.